# ERROR 1442 Can't update table in stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am getting the error **1442** and it's driving me nuts! :)

```
ERROR 1442 Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already 
used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

I am trying to insert a new row in the same table that is updated with a trigger `AFTER UPDATE`. Is this simply impossible or is there a way around it?

thanks!

Comment: You cant do operation viz insert/edit/delete on the same table where the trigger is invoked and that can't be changed.

Comment: Ok it looks like it really isn't possible as of now. And yes there is another question about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252473/mysql-cant-update-rows-when-my-trigger-is-called

Comment: I think I am going to clone my first table structure as a temp table, then insert the data in the temp table, create a trigger on the temp table and update the old table... complicated

Comment: That doesn't work either... I now have 2 distinct triggers on 2 different tables and it's still giving me the same error message. What are my options??

Comment: Please add the trigger codes in to the question.